# JQuery Method not working second Time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, addition

I have a JQuery Method. When I click on button "btnSelectDisclosure", a popup appears but only once. Not for next time. Please help.

```
$(function initJQ() {
        $('#dialogID').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: false,
            minHeight: 20,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            position: 'center'
             ,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("#dialogParentID");
            }

        });

        $('#<%=btnSelectDisclosure.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            $('#dialogID').dialog('open');
            var x = $(this).position().left - document.scrollleft;
            var y = $(this).position().top - document.scrolltop;

            $("#dialogID").dialog('option', 'position', [x, y]);
            $("#dialogID").dialog("option", "show", 'slide');
            return false;
        }
        );


        $('#<%=btnDialogCancel.ClientID%>').click(
        function () {
            $('#dialogID').dialog("close");
        }
    );

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone your dialog template. So just add this:

```
$('#dialogID').clone().dialog({ // etc
```